# Lebesgue integral of f over R is bigger or equal to alpha times measure of $E_\alpha?$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Here is the problem: (1) Suppose that $f \geq 0$ is measurable and integrable. If $\alpha \geq 0$ and $E_α = \{x : f(x) > \alpha\},$ prove that $\lambda(E_\alpha) \leq \frac{1}{\alpha} \int{f(x) dx}.$

Now my question is, how can we have strict equality if my following proof is correct? I guess it isnt?

1) Let $f\geq 0$ be integrable, $\alpha>0, E_\alpha=\{x:f(x)>\alpha\} $
Since $f$ is measurable, $E_\alpha$ is measurable. $\int_{E_\alpha} f dx > \int_{E_\alpha} \alpha dx= \alpha m(E_\alpha) $

Hence $ \int_\mathbb{R} f = \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus{E_\alpha}} f  + \int_{E_\alpha} f > \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus{E_\alpha}} f  + \int_{E_\alpha} \alpha = \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus{E_\alpha}} f  + \alpha m({E_\alpha})  $.

Since $f \geq 0$ then $\int_{R\setminus{E_\alpha}} {f} \geq 0 $
$=> \alpha m(E_\alpha)< \int_\mathbb{R} f $ and dividing by $\alpha$ gives the desired result.

Where is my mistake? Also maybe less importantly, where is the integrability of f used? Even if f is not integrable ie its integral is infinite, the inequality should hold?Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Other than keeping all inequalities nonstrict, it looks fine. The integrability is not really used, it's just that the statement is rather vacuous if $\int f = +\infty$. By the way, this statement is sometimes called Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: Thanks, but why should the inequalities be non strict though?

Comment: For example it could be that $f$ is constant and equal to $\alpha$.

Comment: Ian or another case where f is strictly less than $\alpha$? Basically the point is if $E_\alpha$ has 0 measure, then we would get equality?

Comment: @Ian yes, an integral over a zero measure set is always 0 (because is less that the sup of f .0=0)

Comment: I see that you had $>$. Still, it can't be strict in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Your '>' holds if the measure of $E_{\alpha}$ is positive. If not, you have $\geq$. If $f$ is not integrable the inequallity holds (every set has measure $\leq\infty$ by definition.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. So basically both the integral of f over $E_\alpha$ and the integral of alpha over $E_\alpha$ would be 0 in the case that $E_\alpha$ has 0 measure? Right?Thanks!